# High wire artist

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

We want to derive a Lagrangian equations for a high wire artist which uses a balancing rod for stability purposes. We know the masses and the polar moment of inertia of the artist and the rod.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I had rewritten the question.